# Use CMIS endpoint via tool or script? (no human web login step)

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, cmis

I am trying to access a Rackspace-hosted SharePoint 2013 Demo site via CMIS.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

[image]

I am sure the CMIS URL is correct, because I receive an `app:service` XML file when I connect with this URL/user/password via a web browser.
I tried all 3 `Binding` options, no luck.

I can access the SharePoint web UI normally.

Sounds dumb, but **maybe a human user is required to log in manually** via the web interface before the CMIS endpoint is accessible to this session? Demonstration:

(1) Try to log in via `curl`:

```
$ curl -u MyCorp.user1@raxsp.com:mypass https://mycorp.raxsp.com/personal/mycorp_user1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories
403 FORBIDDEN
```

(2) Try to log in via `Chrome`:

- Type URL `https://mycorp.raxsp.com/personal/mycorp_user1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories`
- I am immediately redirected to [an HTML page](https://mycorp.raxsp.com/_layouts/15/Rackspace.SharePoint.CustomLogin/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/_layouts/15/Authenticate.aspx?Source=%252Fpersonal%252Fmycorp%255Fuser1%252F%255Fvti%255Fbin%252Fcmis%252Frest%253FgetRepositories&Source=/personal/mycorp_user1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories) with a big red `Sign In to SharePoint` button.
- When I click on the button, a browser dialog appears, saying `The server https://mycorp.raxsp.com:443 requires a username and password`
- When I enter username/password and press Enter, the `rest` file is finally downloaded. I am happy, but the human step is a problem, CMIS is for scripts, not for humans.

(3) Trying the link behind the big red button with `curl`:

```
$ curl -u MyCorp.user1@raxsp.com:mypass https://mycorp.raxsp.com/_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=/personal/mycorp_user1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories
```

Result: SharePoint error page saying: `Access is denied. Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration. Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.`

So, how to get rid of this human step, and let a tool/script access the CMIS endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

> Sounds dumb, but maybe a human user is required to log in manually via
>   the web interface before the CMIS endpoint is accessible to this
>   session?

I believe problem is with mode of authentication being used by CMIS or it got something to do with SSL (443).

I remember when I was trying to create a desktop gadget for windows 7 and was trying to get list items from SP 2007 list using HTML, JavaScript and web services but I couldn't as ISA server didn't let me pass through and ended up with same error as yours. I remember of trying hundred of ways but at end I gave up as it worked for HTTP but not for HTTPS.

Comment: The CMIS protocol supports both HTTP and HTTPS, yes. Actually, I have no problem connecting to Alfresco, FileNet, Nuxeo and other CMIS servers with a simple `curl -u user:password https://url-to-cmis-endpoint`... only SharePoint fails at this.